# How to change rear camera to front camera? please help and expland for step

Tags: android, opencv, camera, blob

How to change rear camera to front camera ?

```
          public void setPreview() throws IOException {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture( new SurfaceTexture(10) );
            else
             mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);

     }
```

How to change and use front camera ?

```
        public boolean openCamera() {
            Log.i(TAG, "openCamera");
            releaseCamera();
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            if(mCamera == null) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Can't open camera!");
             return false;
            }
               }
```

How to change camera ?

```
        public void releaseCamera() {
        Log.i(TAG, "releaseCamera");
        mThreadRun = false;
        synchronized (this) {
         if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
        onPreviewStopped();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method by passing boolean values for opening front camera true or false for back camera and please reset camera before calling this method.

```
private void opnenCamera(boolean isFront){
           int cameraCount = 0;
            Camera cam = null;
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

           for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT && isFront ) {
                    try {
                        cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }else if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK && !isFront ) {
                    try {
                        cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
}
```